# Dependency Injection failing in Azure function once deployed but works locally

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-function-app

I have a class which has a public constructor which takes `SqlConnection` as parameter.

```
private readonly SqlConnection _sqlConnection;

public Sample(SqlConnection sqlConnection)
{
    _sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
}
```

In *Startup* file I am trying to do DI

```
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureSQLConnection"));

builder.Services.AddSingleton<SqlConnection>(sqlConnection);
```

It runs locally but when deployed to Azure it fails with error

> System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' while attempting to activate
>   'Test.Sample.Sample'. at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp,Type type,Type requiredBy,Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired) at
>   lambda_method(Closure ,IServiceProvider ,Object[] ) at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs
>   : 37 at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IFunctionInstanceEx
>   functionInstance) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs
>   : 32 at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<.ctor>b__0(IFunctionInstanceEx
>   i) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs
>   : 20 at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.Create(IFunctionInstanceEx
>   functionInstance) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs
>   : 26 at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(IFunctionInstanceEx
>   functionInstance) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs
>   : 44 at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ParameterHelper.Initialize()
>   at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs
>   : 846 at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsyncCore(IFunctionInstanceEx
>   functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs
>   : 117

Comment: That is strange given that you do register it with the service collection.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check namespaces for `SqlConnection` in Startup and `Test.Sample.Sample classes`. The problem is there are two classes with almost the same name (`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` and `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`).
Types have to be the same in both classes.